# How do you find/access community wiki questions?

Tags: support, community-wiki

It is clear how a question or answer can become community wiki, but I can't find any documentation for how to find these questions to participate in answering them.  I came across a few questions in a search that had a [community-wiki](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-wiki) tag (probably here), but no such tag is listed in the tags list and a search on that tag comes up empty.  I also can't find any type of link.  Is this like write-only memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search box supports a variety of extra search terms such as `wiki:yes` ( or ":no") and `is:question`

This search will show you all the questions which are community wiki: https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=wiki%3ayes%20is%3aquestion

On the search page on the right hand side near the top is an "Advanced search tips" link which will show you the extra tools you have.

Comment: That's the best-kept secret on the site.  Thanks.

Comment: For a long time now I've thought that the search results should (optionally?) put Wiki matches at the top of the list (marked as such).  To me it would possibly help prevent 'chains', or 'pools' of duplicates, as it'd make finding the Wiki (which is often/usually Canonical) much easier/more likely.